# Node.js Express: Access token refresh: how to ensure user's request is not interrupted?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, jwt, refresh-token

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to refresh a user's auth tokens without interrupting their original request...

I have one solution, but there's a problem.

Let's say a user logs in, my server generates an **accessToken** and a **refreshToken** using JWT:

- The accessToken is saved in a cookie, it's short-lived, say 15
  minutes, its expiration date is sent directly to the user
- The refreshToken is sent directly to the user and saved in
  localStorage, it's long-lived, say 30 days

For every request that involves accessing resources, the server checks the accessToken cookie for validity. So let's say a user wants to edit their profile: /profile/edit, and the body data is as follows: {name: "My New Name"}

- If the accessToken is invalid (e.g. expires), then the user's request
  is denied and they are redirected back to the login page.
- To ensure an accessToken does not become invalid, the user's web browser will check
  the expiration date of the accessToken (localStorage.getItem("accessTokenExpirationDate"), say every 1 second
- If the accessToken is about to expire, the user will send a /refresh GET request with data: {refreshToken: localStorage.getItem("refreshToken")
- The server then refreshes the access/refresh token and sets them accordingly

**This works.** But the **problem** is if the user closes their browser, comes back in say 30 minutes, and they go back on the website, they will be redirected to the login page, **despite** still having a valid refresh token. Because the timer was not running to actively check the access token expiration, a /refresh request was never sent...

Is there another solution to ensure a user does not get redirected to the login page? How do I refresh the token on the same request?

Or is there an update for my current solution so if the user closes their browser and then returns, they will be able to continue using the website resources normally without having to re-login?

Comment: Simple solution is to always get an access token no matter what. Slightly less simple solution is to always get an access token unless you know for sure (global variable? check your cookies?) that you already have a token.

Comment: If the access token expires then you need to refresh them. I'm not sure what you mean exactly.

My issue is refreshing the token. After I refresh it, I want the user's request to continue. To refresh the token I continuously have the client check the access token's expiry date. When it gets closer, I request a refresh. But this doesn't work if the user closes the browser.

Comment: OK. I may be misunderstanding something here. Can't you just load the page, check the access token and then request from your API? Is the page itself blocked by the token? Normally I don't block accessing the page itself because I normally serve all my front-end files statically from an S3 bucket (no servers). I only protect my APIs.

Comment: Yes I can, but the issue is when the access token expires, I don't want the API request to fail, I want the token to refresh and then the original API request to continue. Apparently this is not possible server-sided, it needs to be done client sided. Also yes I would like GET requests (links/pages) blocked by invalid refresh token as well. I don't want a user seeing a page if they're unauthorized.

Comment: For client side logic you need to load the client side logic in order for the code to run. Your problem is you are preventing your code from loading if the token expires. If the code does not load the browser has nothing to execute. It's a chicken-and-egg problem. If you insist that you MUST block the page (don't want user seeing the page if unauthorized) then you MUST do everything server-side and not manage your tokens client side at all...

Comment: ... if this is really what you want then you MUST use redirects to allow the user to load the page after refreshing the token as if nothing has happened. If this is OK with you I can write an answer based on this. But you must be willing to do a lot of the token management on the server.

Answer (score -1):

Discount, no need to use a login page when a user is already logged in.

If you want to use it then it is necessary to disconnect.

When redirected to the login page, a request is made to receive an access token if the refresh token is valid. If the request was successful
You are returned to the previous page that "threw" the user who was not logged in.

From your question I understand that you store the refresh token in local storage.
Warning! please find alternatives to store refresh-token like http-cookie.
You are exposed to an XSS attack

```
function isAlreadyLoggedin(){
    // load refresh-token exp with convert to Date
    const refreshTokenExpirationDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem("refreshTokenExpirationDate"));

    // case: Refresh-token exp,  User must re-login!
    if (Date.now() > refreshTokenExpirationDate) {
        return;
    }

    // load access-token exp with convert to Date
    const accessTokenExpirationDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem("accessTokenExpirationDate"));

    if (Date.now() > accessTokenExpirationDate) {
        if (renewAccessToken() === true) {
            // browser automatic back to http://your-url/profile/edit
            window.history.back();
        }
    }
}
isAlreadyLoggedin();
```

Comment: Can I get a non-AI generated answer

Comment: You received an answer that I wrote down myself.
In simple words, the login page should check if access token is not valid and refresh has been validly fixed and return to the previous page or make a transfer to any other page.
Those who need the membership page will have to log out first.
In my opinion, this is a clean and acceptable solution on many sites!

Comment: The login page does not validate tokens, it creates them once you successfully login with a username and password. This isn't about logging in, it's about doing requests for resources (such as the index page, editing a profile via POST, etc.). This solution only works for GET requests. I also don't know what you mean by Discount. Your answer and code provided is extremely confusing because I'm using a cookie for the access token and local storage for refresh. I'm fine to use cookies but none of your code is server-sided nor does it work with POST requests with body data.

Comment: If you must prevent the user from loading the page as long as he is not connected
An option is to save the refresh token in a secure cookie and on the server side if the access token is not valid to issue an access token using the refresh token saved in the cookies and then when he opens the browser after more than half an hour the server will already perform a token exchange